# What does it mean for a type bound to refer to itself in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, f-bounded-polymorphism

I was looking through some code on GitHub and came across this type declaration:

```scala
abstract class TreeNode[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]] extends Product with TreePatternBits {
```

(This is [from the Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8dfd3dfc115d6e249f00a9a434b866d28e2eae45/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/TreeNode.scala#L111), though this question is not really about Spark but Scala's type system.)

This is new to me. In plain English, what does this type bound mean?

Comment: Apologies if I take the non-plain English route for a second, but just to give you a way to refer to this in the future, this approach is called "F-bounded polymorphism". You can read more about it [on Wikipedia][2]. I tried to give the plain English route a go but I don't think I understand the concept well enough to do so, so I'll let someone help you in an actual answer. Hopefully the Wikipedia page can give you some idea of what's going on. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hardly anyone reads white papers on System F (mentioned in the comments) and people are still using F-bound type polymorphism intuitively.

All that you need to understand is that class/trait `MyType[A <: MyType[A]]` forces you to extend it as `class Impl extends MyType[Impl]`, that is passing itself as a type parameter.

```
trait Interface[A <: Interface[A]] {

  def getValue: String

  def setValue(value: String): A
}
```

Which is useful if you want to do something like:

```
class Impl(value: String) extends Interface[Impl] {

  override def getValue: String = value

  override def setValue(value: String): Impl = new Impl(value)
}
```

Without this `A <: Interface[A]` (type `A` is a subtype of/extends `Impl[A]`) someone could have implemented:

```
// no F-bound type polymorphism
trait Interface[A] {

  def getValue: String

  def setValue(value: String): A
}

class Foo

class Impl extends Inteface[Foo] {

  override def getValue: String = value

  // we wanted to force implementation to have Impl here but now we cannot
  override def setValue(value: String): Foo = new Foo
}
```

It's useful if you have interfaces which e.g. model some algebras e.g.:

```
trait Number[A <: Number[A]] {

  def add(a: A): A
}
```

To have the implementation the same input/output of methods as its own type:

```
class Integer(val i: Int) extends Number[Integer] {

  def add(a: Integer): Integer = new Integer(i + a.i)
}
```

It's more popular in OOP, as FP offers an alternative approach with the usage of type classes.

Comment: This is a really clear explanation. Thank you 

Comment: I wouldn't say it _"forces"_ since it is pretty easy to bypass that convention: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813323/advantages-of-f-bounded-polymorphism-over-typeclass-for-return-current-type-prob -  nevertheless, as I myself said in the answer, one has to intentionally break it so it is not a big deal.

Comment: I was wondering if you would be able to expand on your mention above that "FP offers an alternative approach with the usage of type classes". How would they solve the `add` definition above?

Comment: @obeattie There is a _lot_ of sources nowadays which shows what are typeclasses and how you can use them. For a particular use case of adding 2 numbers you can google `"scala monoid OR semigroup typeclass"` and get a tons of presentations, blog posts, even official documentation (vide https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/type-classes.html). I won't expand it here as it's not needed for this question and I written enough of this explanations everywhere else to pass on it here.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most widely used examples for motivating a construction like this, is to look at how Java's [`Cloneable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface is broken and how to fix it. (The same argument applies to [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html) as well.)

As you can see, the interface `Cloneable` is actually completely empty, it does not contain any method. And the method which does the actual cloning is [`Object.clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) whose return type is just `Object`. That's not very useful and not very type-safe, since we always need to cast the result of `clone` back to the original type.

Let's assume we want to design an interface for an object that can be cloned.

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney:
  def klon: ???
```

The question is: what should the return type of the `GeorgeCloney.klon` method be? What is the type of the clone of an object?

Well, the type of a clone of an object is the type of the original object. But how do we express that?

In Type Theory, there is a concept called a *MyType*, which allows you to refer to the type of an object itself. Scala doesn't have *MyType*s, but if it did, the interface could look something like this, where `This` is our hypothetical syntax for a `MyType`:

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney:
  def klon: This
```

Now, for example, if we had the following code:

```scala
class Foo extends GeorgeCloney
class Bar extends GeorgeCloney
class Qux extends Bar
```

The return type of `Foo.klon` would be `Foo`, the return type of `Bar.klon` would be `Bar`, and the return type of `Qux.klon` would be `Qux`.

Unfortunately, *MyType* is a very rare feature outside of a small number of academic research languages. The only production-quality, industrial-strength, mainstream programming languages I know of which have a *MyType* feature are [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.SelfTy.html), and [Raku](https://raku.org/) (and you can see that I had to stretch the definition of "mainstream" quite a bit to even get more than one example). Python [will have *MyType* by the end of 2022](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/), which would be another *truly* "mainstream" language to have it.

Now, Scala actually *does* have `this.type` which at first glance might look like it fits the bill:

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney:
  def klon: this.type
```

However, it is actually *too* restrictive: `foo.type` is a [*singleton type*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#singleton-types), i.e. the type which *only* contains the object `foo` itself. Meaning that `this.type` is the type which only contains the object `this` and no other object.

Therefore, the only way to satisfy a return type constraint of `this.type` is to return `this` itself:

```scala
class Foo extends GeorgeCloney:
  def klon = this
```

However, what we actually want to do is to return a new instance of `Foo` with the same internal state as `this`:

```scala
class Foo extends GeorgeCloney:
  def klon = Foo()
```

Which is a type error.

Let's go back to the very beginning. In simplest terms, our interface looks like this:

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney:
  def klon: Any
```

Which forces us to always cast the returned clone to the desired type, which we don't want.

We can actually make the type slightly more precise, since we know that anything which can be cloned implements the `GeorgeCloney` interface:

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney:
  def klon: GeorgeCloney
```

But that is really not an improvement, since we still need to cast anyway, unless all we want to do with the clone is to clone it again. However, let's keep the fact that we can make the type more precise by using the knowledge that anything that is the result of a clone operation must be itself cloneable.

So, what can we do? We want to have a different return type for each cloneable type. So, we need to somehow "tell" the `GeorgeCloney` interface to have a different type for each cloneable type. Well, there is a mechanism for telling something about some information that may be different each time and may not be known at the same place: a *parameter*!

We can add a *type parameter* to the `GeorgeCloney` interface:

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney[A]:
  def klon: A
```

And then use it like this:

```scala
class Foo extends GeorgeCloney[Foo]:
  def klon = Foo()
```

Now, when I call the `klon` method, I get back an object of type `Foo` just like I expect.

However, it is pretty easy to circumvent this:

```scala
class Foo extends GeorgeCloney[String]:
  def klon = "Haha! Fooled you! I am not a clone!"
```

Oops. Now, when I clone a `Foo`, I actually get back a `String`, and this is perfectly type-safe.

But, remember that we said above that we actually know an extra bit of information about the type? We know that `A` must be `GeorgeCloney` itself, because a cloned object can only have come from a cloneable object, and since the cloned and the original object have the same type, we know that both the original and the clone must be cloneable. So, we know that the return value of `klon` is not just an `A` but a "cloneable `A`".

Well, we have already defined what the type of a cloneable `A` is, because that's the very type we have just written: `GeorgeCloney[A]`. So, we know that the `A` in `GeorgeCloney[A]` must itself be a `GeorgeCloney[A]`:

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney[A <: GeorgeCloney[A]]:
  def klon: A
```

If we try the same thing as above, we now get a type error:

```scala
class Foo extends GeorgeCloney[String]:
// Type argument String does not conform to upper bound GeorgeCloney[String]
  def klon = "Haha! Fooled you! I am not a clone!"
```

It is still not nearly as safe as we would like it to be, because I still can do something like this:

```scala
class EvilCloney extends GeorgeCloney[EvilCloney]:
  def klon = EvilCloney()

class InnocentLookingFakeCloney extends GeorgeCloney[EvilCloney]:
  def klon = EvilCloney()
```

When I try to clone `InnocentLookingFakeCloney`, I actually get an `EvilCloney`, not an `InnocentLookingFakeCloney`. However, it is a lot harder to do this *by accident*.

This does not protect against developers who deliberately circumvent the barriers put in place, but it does protect against honest mistakes.

Note that all of the above can be expressed in any type system that has *parametric polymorphism* (aka *generics*), *bounded polymorphism* (i.e. the ability to place constraints on type parameters), and allows the type parameter itself to appear in the constraint. You can do this in Java and C#, for example.

Scala has yet another trick up its sleeve, though: we can further restrict the type by using a *self type annotation*:

```scala
trait GeorgeCloney[A <: GeorgeCloney[A]]:
  this: A =>
  def klon: A
```

Now, we have not only constrained the type parameter to be cloneable itself, we have *also* constrained the type of `this` (i.e. the type of the class which implements this interface) to be the same as the type used for the type argument `A`. Therefore, the `EvilCloney` trick no longer works:

```scala
class EvilCloney extends GeorgeCloney[EvilCloney]:
  def klon = EvilCloney()

class InnocentLookingFakeCloney extends GeorgeCloney[EvilCloney]:
// illegal inheritance:
//   self type InnocentLookingFakeCloney
//   of class InnocentLookingFakeCloney 
//   does not conform to 
//   self type EvilCloney
//   of parent trait GeorgeCloney
  def klon = EvilCloney()
```

However, even this improved version still does not "do the right thing" when it comes to inheritance:

```scala
class EvilCloney extends GeorgeCloney[EvilCloney]:
  def klon = EvilCloney()

class InnocentLookingFakeCloney extends EvilCloney

InnocentLookingFakeCloney().klon
// has type `EvilCloney`, not `InnocentLookingFakeCloney`
```

This is not easily fixable while keeping this particular design, not even with Scala's advanced type system features, and certainly not in a language like Java or C#.

It can, however, be fixed by changing the design to use *type classes* instead of *interfaces*, which can be expressed in Scala (with some boilerplate).

If you are interested in some additional motivating examples, you might want to look at some of the following Stack Exchange answers of mine:

- [Designing shared subtype functionality with correct type annotations in Python](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/435807/1352)
- [PHP - Enforce classes to have method with parameter/return value of `self`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/401974/1352)
- [OOP: Inheriting from immutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360232/2988)
- [How to restrict method's parameter to the class, where the method is overridden](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/375485/1352)
- [Generics vs common interface?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/303299/1352)