# Return Self of different generic

Tags: python, python-typing

In Python typings, am I able to express something like

```py
A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')

class Foo(Generic[A]):
    def map(self, f: Callable[[A], B]) -> Self[B]:
        fields = dataclasses.fields(type(self))
        # do some transformations...
        mapped_fields = ...
        return (type(self))(**mapped_fields)

@dataclass
class Bar(Foo[A]):
    x: A

@dataclass
class Qux(Foo[A]):
    y: A
    z: Bar[A]
    w: Bar[A]

b = Qux("hello", Bar("world"), Bar("!"))
c = b.map(lambda str: len(str))
reveal_type(c) # Qux[int]
c # Qux(5, Bar(5), Bar(1))
```

With `Self[B]` I get the error that `Self` cannot be parameterized. I'm willing to change the definitions of `Foo` and `Bar`/`Qux` (if I need to add more `TypeVar`s to make this work), but as I have a dozen or so `Bar`/`Qux`s I would prefer not to duplicate `map` across all of them.

Comment: What you would need is called [higher kinded types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118095/how-to-use-generic-higher-level-type-variables-in-type-hinting-system), which regrettably is not supported right now in Python's type hinting system.

Comment: I would need [F-bounded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443521/4580217) HKTs, wouldn't I? A-la `class Foo[F[x]: (Foo[F, x],), A]` and `class Bar[A](Foo[Bar, A])` (assuming the 3.12 syntax that I can't use for this project). Or could it be done without that?

Comment: Yeah, that's about what I was envisioning. It would work in Scala, or in Haskell with enough compiler extensions enabled. But not in Python, at least not in 2024 Python.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, because `Self` is meant to be a completely opaque type that unambiguously reference to whatever its underlying concrete type, because otherwise it would create a complicated mess if it's allowed otherwise, see [relevant section in PEP-0673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-generic-classes) for further details.  In that section it has a similar example

```
class Container(Generic[T]):
    def foo(
        self, other: Self[int], other2: Self,
    ) -> Self[str]:  # Rejected
        ...
```

And to adapt their recommendation, you may instead want to modify your provided example function signature to something like the following:

```
class Foo(Generic[A]):
    def map(self, f: Callable[[A], B]) -> Foo[B]:
       ...
```

Comment: Will this allow me to ascribe `Bar[int]` to `someBarStr.map(...)`? I.e. I want the typechecker to not complain about the downcast.